# Customizing chapter's title

Tags: sectioning, chapters

How to make this in LaTex?

[image]

I'm already making the chapter title using this:

```
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
\vspace*{10\p@}%
{\parindent \z@
{\reset@font
\usefont{OT1}{phv}{m}{n}
\LARGE Chapitre \thechapter\par\nobreak}%
\par\nobreak
\vspace*{30\p@}
\interlinepenalty\@M
\usefont{OT1}{ptm}{b}{n}
{\raggedright \Huge #1}%
\par\nobreak
\vskip 20\p@
\hrule height 1pt
\par\nobreak
\vskip 45\p@
}}

\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
\vspace*{10\p@}%
{\parindent \z@
{\raggedleft \reset@font
\scshape \vphantom{\@chapapp{} \thechapter}
\par\nobreak}%
\par\nobreak
\vspace*{30\p@}
\interlinepenalty\@M
\usefont{OT1}{ptm}{b}{n}
{\raggedright \Huge #1}%
\par\nobreak
\par\nobreak
\vskip 45\p@
}}
```

Any brilliant idea, please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an approach with »[titlesec](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec)« where you perhaps need to incorporate your font settings.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
{\filcenter}
{\parbox{\widthof{\LARGE\sffamily\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}\enspace}}{%
  \filcenter\Large\sffamily\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}\enspace\\%
  \fontsize{48pt}{48pt}\selectfont\thechapter}\vrule width 2pt\quad%
}
{0pt}
{\Huge\bfseries\sffamily\parbox{\textwidth-\widthof{\LARGE\sffamily\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}\enspace}}{\filright #1}}

\begin{document}
  \chapter{A Very Long Title with Line Break}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

---

**Addendum**

Correspondingly to the comments this is an adapted (and otherwise slightly enhanced) version with the complete heading in the Helvetica font.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
{\filcenter}
{\parbox{\widthof{\LARGE\sffamily\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}}}{%
   \filcenter\Large\usefont{T1}{phv}{m}{n}\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}\\%
   \fontsize{48pt}{48pt}\selectfont\thechapter%
 }\enspace%
}
{0pt}
{\Huge\usefont{T1}{phv}{b}{n}\vrule width 1pt \enspace%
 \parbox{\textwidth-\widthof{\LARGE\sffamily\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}\enspace}}{\filright #1}%
}

\begin{document}
  \setcounter{chapter}{9}
  \chapter{Chapter Title}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

If you need some kind of subtitle for the chapter as shon in your picture, you will have to use the optional argument.

```
  \chapter[Hello, ATL Server]{Hello, ATL Server\\[6pt] \large A Modern C++ Web Platform}
```

The inclined reader may judge if this is useful or not.

---

[image]

---

And just for the case that you wonder what happens if the chapter title is (unnecessarily) long and goes over more than two lines, you can have a look at this.

[image]

But that should really be avoided. As you can see, the vertical rule adapts to the content of the actual heading whereas chapter name and chapter number stay in their positions.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but what about the font-size and the font-style, please?

Comment: @user3289501: Font sizes except for the chapter number are as in your example. I looked more at the picture when designing the heading. Do you want the chapter number in Times and the heading itself in Helvetica? It seems better to me to put all in Helvetica.

Comment: yes, that's it. But, if you want you can just follow the same font-size and font-style in the posted image.

Comment: @user3289501: I have added a modified example.

Comment: Perfect ! I've upvoted your response.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, also with titlesec, but using tabular environments:

```
        \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
        \usepackage{microtype} 

        \usepackage[svgnames, x11names]{xcolor} 
        \newcommand*\ftsize[1]{\fontsize{#1pt}{\numexpr 1.2*#1\relax pt}\selectfont}
        \newcommand*\chapsubtitle[1]{{\LARGE #1}}
        \newcommand\maketabular[1]{\begin{tabular}[b]{l}
          #1
        \end{tabular}}
        \usepackage{colortbl} 
        \usepackage{titlesec}
        \titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\usefont{T1}{phv}{m}{n}}{%
        \begin{tabular}[b]{c !{\color{lightgray}\vline width1.2pt}}{\large\color{lightgray} \textls*{CHAPTER}}\\[4ex] \fontsize{72}{72}\selectfont\thechapter\end{tabular}}{1em}{\bfseries\fontsize{36}{48}\selectfont\maketabular}%[]


        \begin{document}
        \setcounter{chapter}{12}
        \chapter{Hello,  ATL Server\\ \chapsubtitle{A Modern C++ Web Platform}}%

        \end{document}
```

[image]

If the title has several lines, it still works with a simple modification: instead of one `\\[4ex]`, write as many as the number of title lines.  Here's the result with `\\[4ex]\\[4ex]\\[4ex]` and

```
\chapter{Hello,  ATL Server\\ A Longer Title \\ %
A Still Longer Title \\\chapsubtitle{A Modern C++ Web Platform}}
```

[image]

Still another example, with the table of contents. One needs to use the optional argument of \chapter: 1) because the \subtitle command would be incorporated "as is" (that is, with the \large specifier); 2) in case of a multiple lines title, the titlesec option: `newlinetospace` doesn't seem to work – or I missed something. This option is supposed to automatically replace any \ in a title with a space for use in headers and in the table of contents.

```
        \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
        \usepackage{MinionPro} 
        \usepackage[nomarginpar]{geometry} 

        \usepackage{microtype} 

        \usepackage[svgnames, x11names]{xcolor} 
        \newcommand*\ftsize[1]{\fontsize{#1pt}{\numexpr 1.2*#1\relax pt}\selectfont}
        \newcommand*\chapsubtitle[1]{{\LARGE #1}}
        \newcommand\maketabular[1]{\begin{tabular}[b]{l}
          #1
        \end{tabular}}
        \usepackage{colortbl} 
        \usepackage[explicit,newlinetospace]{titlesec}% 

        \titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\usefont{T1}{phv}{m}{n}}{%
        \begin{tabular}[b]{c}{ \large\color{lightgray} \textls*{CHAPTER}}\\[4ex] \fontsize{48}{48}\selectfont\thechapter\end{tabular}}{1em}{\bfseries\fontsize{24}{30}\selectfont
        \begin{tabular}[b]{ !{\color{lightgray}\vline width1.2pt\ }l}
          #1
        \end{tabular}}
        \titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{2\baselineskip}{6\baselineskip}
        \begin{document}%

        \chapter[The History of the Seven Families of the Lake Pipple-Popple]
        {The History of the\\Seven Families of the\\Lake Pipple-Popple\\
        \chapsubtitle{A nonsense story}}%

       In former days -- that is to say, once upon a time, there lived in the Land of Gramblamble, Seven Families. They lived by the side of the great Lake Pipple-popple (one of the Seven Families, indeed, lived in the Lake), and on the outskirts of the City of Tosh, which, excepting when it was quite dark, they could see plainly. The names of all these places you have probably heard of, and you have only not to look in your Geography books to find out all about them.

       Now the Seven Families who lived on the borders of the great Lake Pipple-popple, were as follows in the next Chapter.

        \tableofcontents

        \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow that's cool, but what about the long titles? It may exceed the large if the paper page!

Comment: How does your implementation work when you also add a ToC?

Comment: @Werner, it's okay!

Comment: You have to add a newline to your title and modify \\[4ex] to \\[another value] to adapt the solution. But I have a serious doubt that you will have a two-lines title _and_ a subtitle. Btw, I've just added some letterspacing to the word: `chapter`.

Comment: Finally it's simpler than trying to find by trial-and-error the exact "another value". Just add as many `\\[4ex]` as the number of lines.

Comment: Making a new line will appear in the TOC.

Comment: But then you have the optional argument of \chapter.

Comment: can you please make a show?